# Adding 2 floats in C

Tags: c, floating-point, type-conversion, double, type-promotion

If I have 2 floats and add them together, is the result a float?  Or is a double?  Or is it compiler defined behavior?

9.0f + 8.0f <--- is the result float, double or compiler defined behavior?

A citation of the correct place in the C specifications would be helpful, if possible.

Comment: The linked duplicate question is C++, not C, and it therefore references the C++ standard, not the C standard. The corresponding place in the C11 standard is [§6.5.6 ¶4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.6p4), which refers to the "usual arithmetic conversions" defined in [§6.3.1.8 ¶1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8). This is explained a bit better [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions).

Comment: B. Nadolson, for further insight, for you, _why_ is the type important?

Answer (score 3):

```
9.0f + 8.0f
```

> is the result a `float`?

Yes, the *type* is `float`.

> First, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `long double`, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is `long double`.

> Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `double`, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is `double`.

> **Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is `float`, the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a type whose corresponding real type is `float`.**

C23x dr § 6.3.1.8 1

---

Although the *type* is `float`, depending on [`FLT_EVAL_METHOD`](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.2p9), the sum may have been calculated using `float`, `double` or `long double` math.  This potentially has arithmetic impact on a larger/different valued expression.  This part is "compiler implementation defined behavior".